# Add two Command Buttons to Solution Explorer Context Menu - Visual Studion Add In

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

The code below should show a custom context menu item when the user right clicks on a "Project" and a different custom context menu item when the user clicks on a "Folder" in Visual Studio 2010 Solution Explorer.

The first part is working just fine - hello new Menu Item yey! - the second part when the user right clicks on Folder - isn't - it always displays the standard old context menu without the new menu item.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? It's ok to create two Command objects, right?

```
public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
    {
        _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
        _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;

        if(connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup)
        {
            object []contextGUIDS = new object[] { };
            Commands2 commands = (Commands2)_applicationObject.Commands;
            CommandBars cBars = (CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars;
            try
            {
                Command commandProjectSettings = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "DavecProjectSchemaSettings", "Davec Project Settings", "Manages Database Project Settings", false, 1, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported+(int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);
                Command commandAddSchemaUpdate = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "DavecProjectUpdate", "Davec Update", "Updates Database Schema", false, 2, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported + (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);

                CommandBar vsBarProject = cBars["Project"];
                CommandBar vsBarFolder = cBars["Folder"];

                commandProjectSettings.AddControl(vsBarProject, 1);
                commandAddSchemaUpdate.AddControl(vsBarFolder, 1);

            }
            catch(System.ArgumentException)
            {
                //ignore
            }

            _solutionEvents = _applicationObject.Events.SolutionEvents;
            _solutionEvents.Opened += new _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler(SolutionEvents_Opened);

            _documentEvents = _applicationObject.Events.DocumentEvents;
            _documentEvents.DocumentSaved += new _dispDocumentEvents_DocumentSavedEventHandler(_documentEvents_DocumentSaved);   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to include new command in the QueryStatus method, which is called when the command's availability is updated i.e.

```
    public void QueryStatus(string commandName, vsCommandStatusTextWanted neededText, ref vsCommandStatus status, ref object commandText)
    {
        if(neededText == vsCommandStatusTextWanted.vsCommandStatusTextWantedNone)
        {
            if (commandName == "Sappha.Davec.VSAddIn.Connect.DavecProjectSchemaSettings")
            {
                status = (vsCommandStatus)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported|vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                return;
            }

            if (commandName == "Sappha.Davec.VSAddIn.Connect.DavecProjectUpdate")
            {
                status = (vsCommandStatus)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```